# Add EKU to CSR using Keytool?

Tags: java, certificate, keytool

How can I add the "Server Authentication" EKU to a CSR or private key using Keytool?

Here is what i'm doing:

1. Generate key-pair with ">Keytool -genseckey -dname="CN="my.server.com" ...
2. Generate CSR using the key-pair created in step #1.
3. Submitting the CSR to a Windows Enterprise CA, asking for a Web Server cert.

The CA rejects the CSR with "The certificate is not valid for the requested usage.".  How can I add the "requested usage" using keytool so that the CA will issue the cert?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this only with the JDK7 or later version of keytool. [OpenJDK 7](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/) should have this version.

Comment: C:\>keytool -genkeypair -alias my.server.com -dname "CN=my.server.com" -ext EKU:true=serverAuth

Awesome, thanks!  Yesterday's snapshot build seems to be working great.